# My desktop icons are sorted when i log on

Tags: unity, nautilus, directory, crash

I have got some folders on desktop. When I move them to different place on desktop and log out they back to default location. I ran sudo nautilus command days ago and I have got my desktop isues. Please help

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is, that your `~/.config/nautilus` folder and/or some of its content is owned by `root`, from when you ran `sudo nautilus`.
If I'm right, you can solve this issue by running in a terminal of some sort:

```
sudo chown -R yourusername: ~/.config/nautilus
```

Comment: I changed ownership but it is still reseting (in alphabetical order)

Comment: have a look at the other files and directories (hidden ones, too) in your home dir. make sure none of those is owned by root.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal from the desktop then enter the following commands:

cd ~/local/share/gvfs-metadata
sudo chown $USER home
chmod 755 home

This allows your desktop software to change/save the icon configuration.
(Thanks to the community for correcting spelling and syntax errors.)